# How to perform a binary search on a file without reading it all into memory at once in c++

Tags: c++

I need a way I can read data from specific places in a file with a binary search.

Comment: Please rephrase your question, I can hardly tell what you problem / question is.

Comment: I take it you mean *"without reading the whole file into memory at one go"*. You've got to read the file, at least a bit, to know what's in it.

Comment: The subject and the question don't work together. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: yes that's what i meant.The reading is just to sort it.

Comment: So, is the question *"how do I do a binary search?"*, or *"how do I read data from specific locations in a file?"*. The answer of course is *"what have you tried?"*, and *"what does [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) say?"*

Comment: I don't follow.... if you're reading to sort, don't you have it in memory already?

Comment: yes I do.I know it's stupid but you can't do a binary search on an unsorted file.The point of the task is to do it without a vector.

Answer (score 4):

There are two possible ways to achieve what you want without reading the whole file into memory. The first (and probably the most robust/portable) is to use positioning API:

- [`std::ifstream::tellg()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg)
- [`std::ifstream::seekg()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg)

Using the above two methods of [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) class you can "navigate" through the file without reading the whole content into memory.

The second way is to simply "map" the file into memory which can be done with "[`mmap()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)", for example. The OS (and its filesystem driver) will take care of paging and reading  data. From your application's point of view it would be just like the whole file was read into memory.

The rest depends on what kind of data you have in your file and how you implement your binary search.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on the data format within the file. To do a binary search within a file, a few things need to be true:

- The data records need to be in sorted order within the disk file.
- You need to have an O(1) means for selecting a record within the file.

If these are both true, then the on-disk binary search works exactly like any other binary search. The difference is that when you fetch the records for comparison, you'll fetch them by seeking to the proper location in the disk file for the record, loading the record from disk, and then comparing based on the record you've loaded.

If take this approach, you'll have to be very mindful of performance. Seeking and reading from a disk is a much slower operation than anything you're used to doing in memory. A disk cache can help you out considerably, but whenever you've moving the disk, you're losing multiple orders of magnitude of performance.